# How do shared memory work with arrays?

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory

I'm just learning about shared memory so far everything I've learnt has confused me.Can some one pleas tell me how shared memory handles an array?And also how tow child processes are to access the said array?

Comment: Just like ordinary memory? (i.e. not at all, memory doesn't handle anything it just stores stuff you put in it.) It would be easier to understand your question is you posted a concrete example of a situation you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use shmat() method to access shared memory,

the shmat() syntex is

```
void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr, int shmflg);
```

this will return a pointer.

If you want to use it as array then allocate as shown below

```
datatype array[size];
datatype* array = (datatype*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: so for int sum it would be: int* sum=(int*)shmat(fd,0,0);

Comment: int* sum=(int*) shmat(fd,NULL,0);

Comment: How can you declare `array` twice? The first time you declared it as an array, hence I feel the head pointer cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

A shared memory area is just a set of consecutive bytes in virtual memory, just like an array. So if you have a pointer to some shared memory, you can treat it just like an array just like any other pointer.